# Distinct digit count

Tags: algorithm, count, distinct, digit

Is is possible to count the distinct digits in a number in constant time `O(1)`?

Suppose `n=1519` output should be `3` as there are `3` distinct digits`(1,5,9)`.

I have done it in `O(N)` time but anyone knows how to find it in `O(1)` time?

Comment: You have to visit each digit. Constant means you would use the same time to calculate n=1 as you would n=123456789

Comment: cheating on input (assuming time needed to split the string and transform it into a set can be left out of the game)

Comment: O(N) for what N? magnitude of n? number of digits (i.e. log)?

Comment: Precalculate all the values, then you can look up the result in O(1) with a simple indexing operation :)

Comment: For a limited boundary, it is possible: build a List<List<Integer>> list, that holds the digits in the list inside, and you can be in O(1) as long as your memory lasts...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Was about to propose the same solution ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet that's a better version of cheating on input ^^

Comment: Also, I have a new idea... For radix 2, you can have it in O(1) :) :) :) :) For _all_ numbers! (insert epic evil genius laugh here)

Comment: @ppeterka: Jon Skeet is like Chuck Norris, he attacks sharks when he smells them bleed :)

Comment: Store the numbers in base 10^N, thus you have only one "digit" and your answer is one.

Answer (score 6):

I assume `N` is the number of digits of `n`. If the size of `n` is unlimited, it can't be done *in general* in O(1) time.

Consider the number `n=11111...111`, with 2 trillion digits. If I switch one of the digits from a `1` to a `2`, there is no way to discover this without in some way looking at every single digit. Thus processing a number with 2 trillion digits must take (of the order of) 2 trillion operations at least, and in general, a number with `N` digits must take (of the order of) `N` operations at least.

However, for almost all numbers, the simple `O(N)` algorithm finishes very quickly because you can just stop as soon as you get to 10 distinct digits. Almost all numbers of sufficient length will have all 10 digits: e.g. the probability of not terminating with the answer '10' after looking at the first 100 digits is about 0.00027, and after the first 1000 digits it's about 1.7e-45. But unfortunately, there are some oddities which make the worst case `O(N)`.

Comment: If the given number fits in the underlying machine word, you have a trivial O(1) algorithm; namely look the answer up in a lookup table as suggested (tongue in cheek) by Jon Skeet. For general sized N, my point remains I think.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get your point. Whatever the word size is, it will be some fixed finite size. So the big-Oh performance of any algorithm that has to deal with arbitrary-sized data is going to be independent of the size of the word. Doing arithmetic on the words doesn't help, even if such operations can be done in O(1) per-word, because the number of words required to express the number n is itself O(N).

Answer (score 2):

After seeing that someone really posted a serious answer to this question, I'd rather repeat my own cheat here, which is a special case of the answer described by @SimonNickerson:

O(1) is not possible, unless you are on radix 2, because that way, every number other than 0 has both 1 and 0, and thus my "solution" works not only for integers...

**EDIT**

> How about 2^k - 1? Isn't that all 1s?

Drat! True... I should have known that when something seems so easy, it is flawed somehow... If I got the all 0 case covered, I should have covered the all 1 case too.

Luckily this case can be tested quite quickly (if addition and bitwise AND are considered an O(1) operation): if x is the number to be tested, compute y this way: `y=(x+1) AND x`. If `y=0`, then `x=2^k - 1`. because this is the only case when all the bits needed to be flipped by the addition. Of course, this is quite a bit flawed, as with bit lengths exceeding the bus width, the bitwise operators are not O(1) anymore, but rather O(N).

At the same time, I think it can be brought down to O(logN), by breaking the number into bus width size chunks, and AND-ing together the neighboring ones, repeating until only one is left: if there were no 0s in the number tested, the last one will be full 1s too...

**EDIT2**: I was wrong... This is *still* O(N).

Comment: How about 2^k - 1? Isn't that all 1s?

Comment: Drat! True... I should have known that when something seems so easy, it is flawed somehow... If I got the all 0 case covered, I should have covered the all 1 case too. Luckily this case can be tested quite quickly (if addition and bitwise AND are considered an O(1) operation): if x is the number to be tested, compute y this way: `y=(x+1) AND x`. If `y=0`, then `x=2^k - 1`. because this is the only case when all the bits needed to be flipped. Of course, this is quite a bit flawed, as with bit lengths exceeding the bus width, the bitwise operators are not O(1) anymore, but rather O(N)...